# Using BQ Command line create View with UDF in BigQuery

Tags: javascript, command-line, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I want to create View in BigQuery using UDF and BQ command line.
BQ command :

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --project_id="myProject" \
'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udfFunc(str STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS 
    """
      data = fromLib(str);
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    """ OPTIONS(library = "gs://<bucket>/lib_file.js");
SELECT'
      col1,
      col2,
      udfFunc(col2) as new_col
    FROM
      `myProject:mySataset.table`'
```

I am getting an error
Invalid value: Routine name "udfFunc" missing dataset while
no default dataset is set in the request.

Comment: looks like error message very clearly answers your question. right? also you should use `myProject.mySataset.table` instead of `myProject:mySataset.table`. Meantime, you can just use temp udf instead of permanent - in this case replace `CREATE OR REPLACE ` with `CREATE TEMP ` and in this case no dataset reference is required

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment :)  but i tired this already it gives an error "Creating views with temporary user-defined functions is not supported"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your query (and the comment on the question), it seems that you only need a temp function during the query time, this is the query that you:

1. define a temp function which is only visible in this query
2. use the temp function immediately in the query

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION udfFunc(str STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS 
    """
      data = fromLib(str);
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    """ OPTIONS(library = "gs://<bucket>/lib_file.js");
SELECT
      col1,
      col2,
      udfFunc(col2) as new_col
    FROM
      `myProject:mySataset.table`
```